# How to find the variance from the probability density function of two variables?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

Suppose I have some arbitrarily chosen probability density function like the one below
$  f(x,y) =
\begin{cases}
f(y),  & \text{0 < x < 2, 0 < y < 1} \\
0, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$

Now I want to compute the variance of X and Y. How can I find the variance of each individual variable from the PDF of *two* variables?

Answer (score 1):

By definition of Variance.

$$\begin{align}\mathsf {Var}(X)~&=~\mathsf E(X^2)-\mathsf E(X)^2 \\[2ex] & = ~\iint_{\Bbb R^2} x^2\,f_{X,Y}(x,y)\operatorname d y\operatorname d x - \left(\iint_{\Bbb R^2} x\,f_{X,Y}(x,y)\operatorname d y\operatorname d x\right)^2\\[2ex] & = ~\int_0^2 \int_0^1 x^2\,f(y)\operatorname d y\operatorname d x - \left(\int_0^2 \int_0^1 x\,f(y)\operatorname d y\operatorname d x\right)^2 \\[2ex] &~~\vdots\end{align}$$

(Tip: Recall that $\int_0^2\int_0^1 f(y)\operatorname d y\operatorname d x = 1$)

---

Likewise the other:

$$\begin{align}\mathsf {Var}(Y)~&=~\mathsf E(Y^2)-\mathsf E(Y)^2 \\[2ex] & = ~\iint_{\Bbb R^2} y^2\,f_{X,Y}(x,y)\operatorname d y\operatorname d x - \left(\iint_{\Bbb R^2} y\,f_{X,Y}(x,y)\operatorname d y\operatorname d x\right)^2\\[2ex] & = ~\int_0^2 \int_0^1 y^2\,f(y)\operatorname d y\operatorname d x - \left(\int_0^2  \int_0^1 y\,f(y)\operatorname d y\operatorname d x\right)^2 \\[2ex] &~~\vdots\end{align}$$